# sequelize Model.hasOne Error: Model is not associated to ModelTwo

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've integrated sequelizejs into my express framework. I got all the models configured and was trying to build my first query with it.

I keep getting the error "Error: Model is not associated to ModelTwo!"

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
 db.Member.findAll({include:[{model:db.MemberProfile,as:'Profile'}]})
 .success(function(users){
  if(users){
   res.json(users);
  }else{
   res.send('no users');
  }
 });
});
```

// model.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize,sql) {
 return sequelize.define('Model', {
  //attributes
 });

 Model.hasOne('ModelTwo',{foreignKey:'model_id'});

};
```

//model_two.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize,sql) {
 return sequelize.define('ModelTwo', {
  //attributes
 });

//no relationship defined. Tried ModelTwo.hasMany('Model',{foreignKey:'id'});
//but it yields the same resulting error
};
```

Any ideas as to what may be going wrong? I'm using the latest version of sequelize 1.7.0-rc6.

Answer (score 28):

This is actually **another case** which throws the same error,

I ran in to the same issue when I try to use `as` option for aliasing when including the model. This will not throw an error as long as you aliased the default name, but you'll get error if you try different name.

The solution,

It clearly says

> If an association is aliased (using the `as` option), *you must specify*
>   this alias when including the model.

This means that, the vise versa as well

> If you want to alias a model when including, it's association must be aliased (using the `as` option).

Comment: Apparently I didn't rtfm closely enough. Thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: Had a really hard time figuring this one out... until I found your answer. Spot on!

Comment: What the hell does that even mean

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out. It seems I needed to use the following in the model definition  to add associations instead of the simple Model.hasOne(bla) which is in the documentation.

```
classMethods:{
  associate:function(models){
    Model.hasOne(models.ModelTwo,{foreignKey:'foreign_key'})
  }
}
```

This code was in the tutorial for express on their site, not in the association documentation.

Comment: this was a lifesaver.

Comment: This should not be necessary

Comment: One year later and I agree with you. This is a HUGE flaw in my opinion, at least in the documentation if not in the code.

Comment: Its not necessary, he was returning before the association in his original code.

Comment: Im am having similliar problem here ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519954/relations-in-sqlize , i tried your solution but did not work either