# use sequelize to get association for the third model

Tags: javascript, model, associations, sequelize.js

I am trying to use sequelize to get the association.

I have 3 models here with the attributes:

students
id, name, class, etc

student_details
studentId, subjectId

subjects
id, subject

I want to get all the subject names for the student and I dont want to store the information in student table directly. Is there a workaround?

Associations are:

models/Student.js

```
classMethods: {
      associate: (models) => {
        Students.studentDetails = Students.hasOne(models.f_student_details, { foreignKey: { name: 'studentId', allowNull: false }, as: 'studentDetails' });
      }
}
```

models/StudentDetails.js

```
classMethods: {
          associate: (models) => {
StudentDetails.belongsTo(models.subjects, { foreignKey: { name: 'subjectId', allowNull: true }, through: 'subjects' });

}
```

models/Subjects.js

```
classMethods: {
          associate: (models) => {
Subjects.hasOne(models.student_details, { foreignKey: { name: 'subjectId', allowNull: false }, as: 'studentSubject' });
}
```

Method Call:

```
db.students.findAll({
include: [ model: db.students]
})
```

Right now, it returns only studentDetails. I want to have subjects via student details in student object. Just to make question clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use nested includes like this:

```
Students.findAll({
    include: {
          model: db.studentDetails,
          include: [ db.subjects ]
    }
});
```

However, you will need to remove the "as" key from the models like below:

models/students.js

```
classMethods: {
      associate: (models) => {
        Students.studentDetails = Students.hasOne(models.f_student_details, { foreignKey: { name: 'studentId', allowNull: false } });
      }
```

models/subjects.js

```
classMethods: {
          associate: (models) => {
Subjects.hasOne(models.student_details, { foreignKey: { name: 'subjectId', allowNull: false } });
}

}
```

models/studentDetails.js

```
classMethods: {
          associate: (models) => {
StudentDetails.belongsTo(models.subjects, { foreignKey: { name: 'subjectId', allowNull: true } });

}
```

Check this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835827/sequelize-model-hasone-error-model-is-not-associated-to-modeltwo)

Comment: I will try and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks. You are a life saver!

Comment: Glad, I could help you :)